# local or global?

Tags: javascript

I have many functions like this, and I don't know should I make j and k a local variable or will there be any abnormal problems?

```
var j=10,k=20;
var i=j+k*2;
console.log('helloworld'+i);
function plus(j,k){
 var i=j+k;
 console.log('plus '+i);
 //...etc
}

function formular(j,k){
 var i=j*k+123;
 console.log('formular '+i);
 //...etc
}
plus(-10,-20);
setInerval(function(){formular(22,33)},1000);
setInerval(function(){plus(-102,-33)},1000);
```

Or should I write like

```
function(var j, var k){ }
```

??

Comment: Can you give actual examples instead of weird functions with poorly named variables? i and j are almost exclusively used as loop variables in for loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var j=10,k=20;
var i=j+k*2;
console.log('helloworld'+i);
```

Here, `i`, `j` and `k` are both global (assuming you code is under global);

```
function plus(j,k){
 var i=j+k;
 console.log('plus '+i);
 //...etc
}
```

Here, `j`, `k` and also `i` is local, because `j` and `k` is defined in function parameter list and `i` is defined inside function.

The above two will not conflict; Try this: [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mD9dm/). Press the two buttons at any sequence.

I'm not saying that your code is a good practice, though. Keep in mind that **global variable should be used in caution**.

Answer (score 0):

This is really bad practice. Global variables should be used sparingly in javascript. Naming your function arguments with the same names as your globals is even worse and will get confusing quickly.

No, you should not be writing
    function(var r,var k)

Try and use local variables whenever possible, and never confuse yourself by naming them the same way you name your globals.